# Terminal and Software center error, Please help

Tags: command-line, apt, software-center, dpkg

Whenever I do

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I get this error output:

```
abs@abs-Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
[sudo] password for abs: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 liboxideqt-qmlplugin : Depends: liboxideqtcore0 (= 1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) but 1.5.5-0ubuntu1 is installed
 liboxideqtcore0 : Depends: oxideqt-codecs (= 1.5.5-0ubuntu1) but 1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 is installed or
                            oxideqt-codecs-extra (= 1.5.5-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
 liboxideqtquick0 : Depends: liboxideqtcore0 (= 1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) but 1.5.5-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
abs@abs-Ubuntu:~$
```

And if I do: `sudo apt-get autoremove -f` (as it says):

```
abs@abs-Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove -f
[sudo] password for abs: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  liboxideqtcore0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  liboxideqtcore0
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 266 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/27.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,621 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 205974 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../liboxideqtcore0_1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking liboxideqtcore0:i386 (1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) over (1.5.5-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/liboxideqtcore0_1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libOxideQtCore.so.0' to '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libOxideQtCore.so.0.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/liboxideqtcore0_1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
abs@abs-Ubuntu:~$
```

I don't know if this is linked but whenever I go into the **Ubuntu Software Centre** a window pops up saying: "New software cannot be installed, because there is a problem with the software currently installed. Do you want to repair this problem now?" If I hit "Repair" and I input my password for authentication it says "Package operation failed" and this is the output in the details section:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 205974 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../liboxideqtcore0_1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking liboxideqtcore0:i386 (1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) over (1.5.5-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/liboxideqtcore0_1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libOxideQtCore.so.0' to '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libOxideQtCore.so.0.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/liboxideqtcore0_1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_i386.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of liboxideqtquick0:i386:
 liboxideqtquick0:i386 depends on liboxideqtcore0 (= 1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1); however:
  Version of liboxideqtcore0:i386 on system is 1.5.5-0ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package liboxideqtquick0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of liboxideqt-qmlplugin:i386:
 liboxideqt-qmlplugin:i386 depends on liboxideqtcore0 (= 1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1); however:
  Version of liboxideqtcore0:i386 on system is 1.5.5-0ubuntu1.
 liboxideqt-qmlplugin:i386 depends on liboxideqtquick0 (= 1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1); however:
  Package liboxideqtquick0:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package liboxideqt-qmlplugin:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Please help, I don't know how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first step would be to execute the suggested command as printed, which is `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: It seems like `apt-get` is trying to install a corrupted version of `lliboxideqtcore0`. Try to remove the corrupted cached version (`sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/liboxideqtcore0_1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_i386.deb`) and run `sudo apt-get install -f` again

Comment: It worked @kos, thank you so much! I got 1 question: What does the 'rm' do in the sudo command?

Comment: Glad that it helped. `rm` simply removes the file/files following as arguments, i.e. in this case it deleted `/var/cache/apt/archives/liboxideqtcore0_1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_i386.deb`, the corrupted file, forcing `sudo apt-get install -f` to download it another time. I posted an answer below with all the details. If you have a minute please accept it by clicking on the grey tick under the answer's votes :)

Comment: Ah, makes sense :) Thanks again bro. and yea I've accepted it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of `liboxideqtcore0` you have in your APT cache is corrupted.

To fix this, remove it:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/liboxideqtcore0_1.9.5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_i386.deb
```

and run `sudo apt-get install -f` again:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This will force `apt-get` to download another (hopefully not corrupted) version of `liboxideqtcore0`, which should install without problems.